# Rate of Convergence in Big-Oh Notation

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Let:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1-e^x}{x}
$$
Then:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = -1
$$
Question: I am looking for the way to express the rate of convergence of this limit in relation to a polynomial, using the big-Oh notation.

Attempt: a polynomial function that has the same limit is:
$$
g(x)= -1-x
$$
And by looking at the graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, we can see that:
$$
|f(x)|<|g(x)| \text{, for small x}
$$
So I believe I can write:
$$
f(x) = -1 + O(x) \text{, as x $\to 0 $}
$$
Please let me know if my thought was correct. If yes, how do I formally derive the result without relying on the graph? Otherwise, please give me some hints to solve this problem.

Comment: As $x\to a$, $f(x)=O(g(x))\iff \lim_{x\to a}sup |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|<\infty$. So I guess you are right in this question

Comment: @Abigail Can you derive this result formally?